# How can I put the values in the table into the polygon function in the postgresql platform?

Tags: postgresql, postgis

[image]

How can I put the values in the table into the polygon function?

Note : `ST_GeomFromText('LINESTRING(75 29,77 29,77 29, 75 29)')` --coordinates are representations. What I want is to put the values in the table into the function.

Comment: Please post the table definition(s) and the query you're working with as text, as well as some sample data so that we can reproduce the problem.

Comment: SELECT ST_MakePolygon( ST_GeomFromText('LINESTRING(75 29,77 29,77 29, 75 29)') ) FROM
(SELECT ogc_fid, wkb_geometry, ST_AsText(wkb_geometry) FROM madened50 WHERE ogc_fid between 50 and 59) p1;

Comment: You can [edit] your question and [use code formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) in there

Answer (score 0):

you **could** use the geometry directly (**if** they were suitable, which they are not, see below).

```
SELECT ST_MakePolygon(wkb_geometry) FROM madened50 WHERE ...
```

BUT, a polygon is made of at least 4 points, with the 1st and last point being the same. In your table, the lines have 2 points only, so how exactly do you want to make a polygon from a line?

Don't forget that you can't just add one of point multiple times (the polygon will be invalid where the vertex is repeated, and a lot of function won't work properly with invalid geometries)

If it was only for the last point, which must be the same as the 1st one, you could add it though

```
SELECT ST_MakePolygon(ST_AddPoint(wkb_geometry, ST_StartPoint(wkb_geometry))) 
FROM madened50 WHERE ...
```